# Exporting from MSAccess to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps, ms-access, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to save a couple steps in my workflow before I hand off this maintenance task to an administrator.

Here is my current workflow:

1. Export the results of an SQL query in MSAccess to an XLS file, which include Google Maps coordinates and other infoWindow data.  MSAccess 2013 (no google cloud support yet).
2. Open my existing/published google spreadsheet, which is the data source for a Google Maps app:
3. Select "File > Import", select "Replace Spreadsheet", click "Choose File", navigate my laptop to find the file...

Question - 2 parts:

1. Is it at all possible to export the results of my query directly to that Google Spreadsheet?
2. Else, is it possible to synchronize an XLS on my laptop and an associated Google Spreadsheet?

Hope you can assist!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

google apps script will let you setup a jdbc connection
There is an example here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#reading_from_a_database

You would also need to register ODBC for the access file.